# Does Trunks have god ki already?

Tags: dragon-ball-series, dragon-ball-super, dragon-ball-manga

In the discussions about Dragon Ball Super, it's always been wonder if Trunks got some level of god ki after transforming into "Super Saiyan Rage" , since there's partially a blue aura and some features of the ki are drawn similar to those of a Super Saiyan Blue and not a regular Super Saiyan. Now in the preview of Dragon Ball Super manga chapter 24, it's been revealed that...

> Trunks became a Kaioshin apprentice and because of the ability of healing people just like Kibito did. We know kaioshin have god ki, does a kaioshin apprentice also have some sort of management of god ki, making Trunks able to have some sort of management of god ki already?

Answer (score 2):

Recall how Goku had his Super Saiyan God. Although Trunks is Kaioshin Appr. It does not satisfy your question if he has god ki or not.

Having a blue aura before the normal super saiyan aura doesn't mean he got the aura of a god.

To make things simple since I'm watching Dragon Ball Super. Goku needs a combination of 5 people who have the blood of Super Saiyan before he had it so I think Trunks also need that too in order to achieve it.

Comment: but your assumption is wrong, because Vegeta didnt need 5 persons to get god ki. Neither Beerus did. BTW, you might want to make visible only to mouse over the part of the text where you are spoiling with the >! tag

Answer (score 2):

I think it's due to exposure from SSJB Goku and Vegeta and SSJR G/Black Godly Ki, being exposed to that ki for so long in fights may have caused Trunks to "absorb" some of it.

Similar to Vegeta; he acquired the power of a god by himself, which leads to think that he, alongside the other Saiyans, absorbed some of the god ki while doing the ritual to make Goku a god.

It's just a matter of being in the right circumstances to nurture and make something of the god ki.

Answer (score 2):

I think Trunks does have some God Ki. He was the only one who survived the attack from the androids (yeah, it was with Gohan's training but that doesn't matter) and he was the only one who could kill Fused Zamasu. So, it would make sense that he has some God Ki inside him because how come neither Goku or Vegeta could kill Zamasu in his regular form with SSB (being stronger than SSG since its SSG+SSJ)

And somehow, Trunks ends him with the Spirit Bomb Sword. He has to obtain that massive power somehow. And him having God Ki would explain it. Zamasu may be immortal, but, he's not a god. And if his father is ascended pass a SSG, then what says he can't either or at least have the power inside him to do it too?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm wrong, but SSJ Rage looks a lot like The Legendary Super Saiyan transformation by both Broly and Kale, just lacked the green aura.

Trunks even says in the episode, "If you think my choices make me evil, then that's what I'll be." So he turned to a darker side to fight for his friends. Maybe that's why the aura is different.